# Prove the solutions to $ax+by=c$

Tags: proof-writing, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

I have this math question, that I'm kind of stuck on.

> Consider the equation $a x + b y = c$, for some non-zero integers $a,
>  b$ and $c$.  Suppose that $x = x_1, y = y_1$ is an integer solution to
>    the equation $ax + by = c$.
>
> It is know that if $x, y$ is an integer solution to the homogeneous
>    equation $a x + by = 0$, then $$ x = \frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)} k,
>    y= - \frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)} k,  \text{ for some
>  integer } k. $$ Use this fact to show that if $x=x_2, y=y_2$ is
>    another solution to the equation  $a x + b y = c$, then $$ x_2 = x_1+
>  \frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)}k,   y_2=y_1 -
>  \frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)}k, \text{ for some integer } k. $$

I'm not sure how to start this. Would I just plug in $x_2$ and $y_2$ for $x$ and $y$? Thanks

Comment: This is different from your previous problem. In that one, you needed to verify that a cetain $(x,y)$ was a solution. Now you have to prove a harder result, that all solutions must have that particular shape. So plugging in is now not enough.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$ ax_2+by_2=c=ax_1+by_1\Rightarrow a(x_2-x_1)+b(y_2-y_1)=0 .$$

Answer (score 0):

$$ax_2 + by_2 = c= ax_1 + by_1 ⇒ a(x_2 −x_1 )+b(y_2 −y_1 )=0.$$

$$a(x_2-x_1)= -b(y_2-y_1)$$
Divide by $g=(a,b)$ to get $$\frac{a}{g}(x_2-x_1)=-\frac{b}{g}(y_2-y_1)$$

Since $(\frac{a}{g},\frac{b}{g})=1$, we have $$\frac{a}{g} \mid (y_2-y_1)$$

The rest is straightforward.